# Is there a way to generate the actual column types instead of domain names?

Tags: sql-server, powerdesigner

I am using PD 16.6.6.1 with MS SQL Server 2008.

I declared a domain name AnyVal mapped to the sql_variant type.

I assigned this domain to a column called Value. When PD generates the sql code in the Preview it generates: `Value ANYVAL not null,`. Is there a way to tell PD to generate `Value sql_variant not null`?

I could not find a setting to do that. Other data modeling tools (Toad Data Modeler and ER Studio) do this by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating a script with `Database > Generate Database`, in the `Options` tab, in `Table & Column > Column`, this is controlled by the `User data type` checkbox.

If you uncheck it, PowerDesigner will generate the base type instead of the user-defined type, generated from the domain.

I guess this is a question of preference: if you define the data types of the columns with a domain in PowerDesigner, it puts more information in the system tables, if you use the user-defined type to create the columns in the database.